# In NUnit how to add a test that runs with all the parameters of another test?

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

I have a parameterised test that unit tests a certain logic. There are several test cases captured by the NUnit `TestCaseAttribute`.

Now I wish to utilize exactly the same parameters to test a slightly different logic.

I realize that I can deliver the parameters through a different attribute - `TestCaseSourceAttribute` and use the same source for multiple unit tests.

But I wonder if one can both use `TestCaseAttribute` (which I find more convenient in this particular test) and reuse the parameters for another test?

My solution involves reflection:

```
[TestCase(Impl.SqlErrorCode.PartiallyDocumentedColumn, 1978.14, "MyTable", ChangeTypeCode.AddTable, "dbo.MyAuxTable:MyTableId")]
[TestCase(Impl.SqlErrorCode.UndocumentedColumn, 1978.15, "MyAuxTable", ChangeTypeCode.AddTable, "dbo.MyAuxTable:MyAuxTableId")]
[TestCase(Impl.SqlErrorCode.UndocumentedColumn, 1978.16, "MyTable", ChangeTypeCode.AddTable, "dbo.MyTable:MyAuxTableId")]
[TestCase(Impl.SqlErrorCode.NonExistingColumnInComments, 1969.19, "MyTable", ChangeTypeCode.None, "dbo.MyTable:Remarks")]
public async Task AddTableWithBadComments(Impl.SqlErrorCode expectedSqlErrorCode, decimal step, string tableName, int sqlErrorState, string expectedObjectName)
{
    // ...
}

private static IEnumerable GetParametersOfAnotherTest(string testName)
{
    var testCaseAttrs = typeof(IntegrationTests).GetMethod(testName).GetCustomAttributes<TestCaseAttribute>();
    return testCaseAttrs.Select(a => a.Arguments);
}

[TestCaseSource(nameof(GetParametersOfAnotherTest), new object[] { nameof(AddTableWithBadComments) })]
public async Task AddTableWithBadCommentsNoVerify(Impl.SqlErrorCode expectedSqlErrorCode, double _step, string tableName, int sqlErrorState, string expectedObjectName)
{
    // A different logic, but with the same parameters.
}
```

It has some problems though.

So, my question is this - is there an NUnit way to run a test method Y with the parameters of the test method X, where the latter uses `TestCaseAttribute` to provide the parameters?

I use nunit 3.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual answer is quite short. The NUnit way to reuse parameters is `TestCaseSourceAttribute`. :-)

I thought I would explain why your solution doesn't work.

In NUnit 3+, attributes like `TestCase` and `TestCaseSource` are not just containers of data. They implement interfaces, which NUnit calls in order to have the attributes operate on a particular test.

Your code is treating `TestCaseAttribute` as if it were no more than a data store for arguments. But the attribute actually does some things and some of them are different from what `TestCaseSourceAttribute` does.

From your code, I can see you figured part of that out yourself. Your first method relies on the attribute converting double to decimal, while your second takes the argument as a double. That difference is of course due to the fact that you can't have a decimal argument to an attribute.

Unfortunately, for a full solution, you would have to duplicate or make allowances for other differences between the two attributes, which are all due to the restrictions C# places on attribute arguments. IMO, it's not worth it. It's trivial to create a static array of TestCaseData items and use them for both methods. If you make your approach work (which is possible) it's only advantage will be in its cleverness. :-)